# See if the end of strings match

Tags: javascript, string

I have this exercise: Check if a string (first argument, str) ends with the given target string (second argument, target) without using the method `endsWith()` or any other method. What's wrong with my code?

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= target.length; i++) {
    val = false
    if (str[str.length - i] === target[target.length - i]) {
      val = true;
    }
    return val;
  }
}
confirmEnding("Bastian", "n");

//original code from post above:
console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "n")); //added to provide working example
```

Comment: Each iteration of the loop - and therefore, in particular, the first iteration - `return`s either `true` or `false` depending on a comparison. So all you're actually checking is the first iteration. You should remove the `else` and move the `return false` to after the loop.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging or logging? What happens when you "return" from a funtion? Will the loop keep executing?

Comment: what about now I just modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code there are a few problems:

Will address them inline:

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  // using a for loop to iterate over the target string's length
  for (var i = 1; i <= target.length; i++) {
    //setting up a variable that says false
    val = false
    //trying to compare the individual characters
    if (str[str.length - i] === target[target.length - i]) {
      //so what happens here:
      //when the two match this will set val to true
      //but every time the loop is run is will reset to false.
      val = true;
    }
    //the return value is in the loop, so the loop will run once
    return val;
  }
}
confirmEnding("Bastian", "n");
```

With the above script you have no way of knowing if all the characters match. If the last character matches it will return true, even if the other characters don't match.

```
string: Bastian target: irr
```

Will return true in the logic of your loop.

Take a look at the code below and the comments in it!

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  //get the length of the target string
  const targetLength = target.length;
  //set up an empty string  
  let endstr = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= targetLength; i++)
  {
    //start at 1 since str.length-1 is last character
    //fill the empty string with the last characters of str
    endstr = str[str.length-i] + endstr;
  }
  //compare and return
  return target === endstr;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "ian")); //TRUE
console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "in")); //FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your current code is that the variable for the result is initialised inside the loop.

So it actually only returns true/false depending on the last character it compares.
Which would be the first character of the target string.

What you can do is get out of that loop as soon a difference is found.

And additional, also check if the string isn't smaller than the target, because then it would be false anyway.

F.e.

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
    if(str.length < target.length)
        return false;
    for (var i = 1; i <= target.length; i++) {
        if (str[str.length - i] !== target[target.length - i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "ian")); 
console.log(confirmEnding("Bastian", "ion"));
console.log(confirmEnding("an", "ian"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const confirmEnding = (str,target) => str.slice(-target.length) === target;

console.log(confirmEnding('peace','ace')); // true
console.log(confirmEnding('devotion','tio')); // false
console.log(confirmEnding('faith and love','nd love')); // true
```

we know that "slice" take 2 arguments: [ index | how many items ]

more so, a negative index would start extracting characters from the end of a string

we can use this to our advantage by utilizing the "length" property from "target" to set the "index" on the "slice" method

let's use "peace" as our example to breakdown the code:

1. ('peace','e') => str.slice(-1) === 'e';

   - str.slice(-1) --> return the last character 'e' from "peace"
2. ('peace','e') => 'e' === 'e'; --> "true"